# Shell script - Redirect to file not working after editing the file manually

Tags: shell, sh

I have a script file that runs following. It actually runs a Java application and console logs are redirected to a log file.

```
$JAVA_CMD $APP_ENV $APP_MAIN_CLASS >>&! $LOGFILE &
```

It runs fine. I tried editing the file manually when the process is running. But the problem is, after I edit the file, and when I do some operation in the application, there are no logs appended to the existing file anymore.

Why is that? And how to Resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit a file while it is being written to.  Most editors will end up moving the file to a different inode, at least temporarily, while your Java process only has a file handle to a file which has now ceased to exist.

The fundamental concept here is that a file is basically a unidirectional sequence. Appending to a file while something earlier in the sequence is modified by another process is simply not well-defined.

A common workaround is to copy the file before editing it; another, for log files, is to implement some sort of log file rotation mechanism (so you can say "let go of the log and start a new one, please"), but then simple redirection won't work for writing to the log.